# Excel VBA reference issues

Tags: excel, vba

I was following some examples online in which im trying to pass a value from one sub into a another sub in VBA but get the error:

Compile Error:
Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name.

```
Sub next_sat_click()

Dim iweekday As Integer
Dim nextsat As String
Dim index As Integer
Dim str_game_date As String

iweekday = weekday(Now(), vbSunday)

nextsat = Format((Now + 7 - iweekday), "mm-dd-yy")

Call set_button_Click(nextsat)

End Sub

Sub set_button_Click(ByRef nextsat As String)
......
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a button called `set_button`?  If so, it is going to be getting upset that you changed the parameters that its `Click` event was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Change the sub name in something else like SetButtonOnClick.

The _Click keyword is reserved by excel for the Click event on buttons if you have a button called with the same name.

Comment: i do have a button called set_button with a click action. So can i just remove the _click from the sub procedure even though that is the code for that button? Or how else can i pass a value into that sub procedure?

Comment: because what im trying to do is in my userform when next_sat_click is clicked it calculates the next saturday date then pass that value as a string to set_button_click. Then when the set_button is pressed in the userform write that date to the excel file. If thats even possible or a different way i should approach it.

Comment: Simply when Next_sat_click is clicked directly write that date into the excel file, or, if you are like i imagine in a userform, create a textbox where next_sat_click will save that date, and with set_button_click simply get the value from the textbox and save it where you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the parameters for an event handler (except for the parameter name). That also means you can't *add* any parameters if none are expected. Not even `Optional ByRef nextsat As String` will work.

There are three ways to pass a value between event handlers in a UserForm:

1. Using a global variable (not recommended, ***ever***);
2. Via the `UserForm.tag` property (recommended for simple values such as strings). Obviously cannot be used if it already has a permanent use;
3. Via one or more *hidden* controls (recommended for multiple or complex values as well as simple ones).

I've used the second method:

```
Sub next_sat_click()

Dim iweekday As Integer
Dim nextsat As String
Dim index As Integer
Dim str_game_date As String

iweekday = Weekday(Now(), vbSunday)

nextsat = Format((Now + 7 - iweekday), "mm-dd-yy")

Me.Tag = nextsat

End Sub

Sub set_button_Click()
Dim nextsat As String
nextsat = Me.Tag
......
End Sub
```

A better solution in your case might be to have a *visible* TextBox in which you store the calculated date when the user clicks `next_sat`, so that the user can see it. Then in your `set_button` handler, grab it from `TextBox.Text`.

Comment: i'll surely give that a shot. Thanks!